# WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: invalid internalformat - depthTexture in webgl2

Tags: javascript, webgl, matrix-engine

```
const depthTextures = gl => {
  const depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
  const depthTextureSize = 512;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
  0, // mip level
  gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, // internal format
  depthTextureSize, // width
  depthTextureSize, // height
  0, // border
  gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, // format
  gl.UNSIGNED_INT, // type
  null); // data

  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  const depthFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, depthFramebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, // target
  gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, // attachment point
  gl.TEXTURE_2D, // texture target
  depthTexture, // texture
  0); // mip level
  // create a color texture of the same size as the depth texture
  // see article why this is needed_

  const unusedTexture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, unusedTexture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, depthTextureSize, depthTextureSize, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE); // attach it to the framebuffer

  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, // target
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, // attachment point
  gl.TEXTURE_2D, // texture target
  unusedTexture, // texture
  0); // mip level

  return [depthFramebuffer, unusedTexture];
};
```

I found

> Note: This extension is only available to WebGL1 contexts. In WebGL2,
> the functionality of this extension is available on the WebGL2 context
> by default. The constant in WebGL2 is gl.UNSIGNED_INT_24_8.

I change `DEPTH_COMPONENT` with `RGBA` but still no attaced framebuffer...

In other combination i get :

```js
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,      // target
    0,                  // mip level
    gl.RGBA, // internal format
    depthTextureSize,   // width
    depthTextureSize,   // height
    0,                  // border
    gl.RGBA, // format
    gl.UNSIGNED_INT_24_8,    // type
    null);              // data
```

```
 GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Invalid combination of format, type and internalFormat.

 GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Only array uniforms may have count > 1.
```

Any suggestion ?

This is source which i wanna implement in my own already exist glmatrix project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal format of a depth texture cannot be `RGBA`, it must be one of the size internal formats e.g. (`GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`, `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`) . If the source format is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, the source type must be either `FLOAT` or one of the unsigned integral types. The internal format must be one of the valid combinations together with the format and type, (see OpenGL ES 3.0 [`glTexImage2D`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)). Valid textures for an `gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` are therefore e.g.:

```js
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
    gl.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 
    depthTextureSize, depthTextureSize, 0,
    gl.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    null);
```

```js
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
    gl.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 
    depthTextureSize, depthTextureSize, 0,
    gl.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.GL_FLOAT,
    null);
```

Alternatively, you can use a combined depth and stencil texture (in this case it is a `gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` instead of a `gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`), e.g:

```js
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 
    gl.GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 
    depthTextureSize, depthTextureSize, 0,
    gl.GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8,
    null);
```

Comment: I still get `WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: texImage2D: invalid format`

Comment: I found https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html i will try it...

Comment: @NikolaLukic This page uses `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24`, `gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT`, `gl.UNSIGNED_INT`, like the first examples in my answer.